# GCP creating load balancer service using existing static IP doesn't show external ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to host a wordpress website on GKE and then create a ELB with a pre-existing static IP to expose wordpress. I did the following things:

- Reserved a static IP as defined here: [Link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static). It is of type IPv4, Premium Tier and Global.
- Created a ELB Service following(modified yaml to my static ip) [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk#expose_the_wordpress_service).

Contents of my yaml:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: wordpress
  name: wordpress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "x.x.x.x"
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wordpres
```

When I run the following command - `kubectl get svc -l app=wordpress --watch`, I get:

```
NAME        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
wordpress   LoadBalancer   x.x.x.x   <pending>     80:32590/TCP   6m7s
```

Any clues why this is not working and giving me the external ip address?

Comment: How long did you give it?  I have been reading stories that it may take up to 15 mins.

Comment: 18 mins till now but still doesn't work

Comment: did you check on the console, in the loadbalancing menu, what the loadbalancer deployment status was?

Comment: It looks like you're specifying the internal ClusterIP as the `loadBalancerIP`, not the IP address that you reserved and want to use...  They're both 192.168.0.1, and I'd be surprised if your static loadbalancer address ended in .1 (and 192.168.x.x would never be an external IP)

Comment: that was just for sample. I should have given it as x.x.x.x my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we expose  a Service, it creates a TCP Network Load Balancer that works with Regional IP addresses only. Global IP addresses only work with Ingress resource type. I would recommend you using a Regional static IP address, instead of Global. Here is the link that gives a brief description of Load Balancers in GCP:[1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary_of_cloud_load_balancers) I tried replicating this scenario on my end, and it worked for me with a Regional IP address immediately and did not work the Global IP address at all.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip this states global IPs can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your service spec looks wrong. The `spec.loadBalancerIP` field should specify the "external" IP that you want assigned to the LB front end (note that external here means external to the cluster, this IP should belong to your VPC or be a public IP).

In your case, the IP you assigned (`192.168.0.1`) is actually your clusterIP (which makes sense due to how Google assigns IPs in VPCs, that IP would normally be assigned to a gateway). Whatever your static IP is (let's say `35.35.35.35`), that should be specified in the proper field as `spec.loadBalancerIP: 35.35.35.35`. The `192.168.0.1` would be defined in the `spec.clusterIP` field if that was necessary at all.

Comment: that was just for sample. I should have given it as x.x.x.x my bad. It is not 192.168.0.1.

Comment: Is the IP you chose appearing as the clusterIP? Can you also confirm the lb ip is reserved and unassigned?